# set option value in select2 dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter, jquery-select2

I make a form. In one of the input I'am using select2 ajax to search data on the database, then click it to the data you want to choose.The problem is when I submit the form, it get error because one of the input is null(that's the input in select option). I don't know why the value is still null, even I've clicked on the one of the option.Can anyone help me??? 
Thank You :)

here's my view

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <?php echo form_open('company2/masuk') ?>
  <form>
  <select id="Name" class="searching form-control" style="width:500px" name="company"></select>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light">Save</button>
 <?php echo form_close(); ?>
 </form>
  </body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $('.searching').select2({
            placeholder: 'Masukkan Nama Company',
            ajax:{
                url: "<?php echo base_url('company2/select2'); ?>",
                dataType: "json",
                delay: 250,
                processResults: function (param) {
        return {
          compClue: param.term,

        };
      },
      processResults: function(data){
                    var results = [];

                    $.each(data, function(index, item){

                        results.push({
                            id: item.Name,
                            text: item.Name,
                            value:item.Name
                        });
                    });
                    return{
                        results: results,
                        cache: true,
                    };
                }
            }
        });
```

Here's my controller

```
public function masuk(){
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->load->helper('url_helper');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('Name', 'Name', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('CreatedOn', 'CreatedOn', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('Status', 'Status', 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
  $this->add_company();

  }else{
  $this->company_model->buat();
    redirect('company2/index');
    }
 }
```

My Model

```
   public function buat(){
$data = array(
  'Name' => $this->input->post('Name'),
  'CreatedOn' => $this->input->post('CreatedOn'),
  'Status' => $this->input->post('Status')
);
return $this->db->insert('dbo.Company', $data);
 }
```

Comment: if your issue is with submitting, why show us all this unrelated code? where is your post controller. have you tried any debugging steps to determine what is getting sent i.e. dev tools, print_r, .etc.?

Comment: sorry, I've changed it

Comment: ok, but as far as debugging steps, what exactly happens when you submit the form? console error? validation error? does `buat()` get called?

Comment: I get validation error because one of the value is null (the input Name). Im using select option in the input Name, when I choose the option it can't set the value of Name on it.

Comment: @kitcat why two "processResults" function here? Add select2 php function here..

Comment: I just realized that, I followed some step on the Internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite `name="company"` ***To*** `name="Name"`

OR

Rewrite `$this->form_validation->set_rules('Name', 'Name', 'required');` ***To*** `$this->form_validation->set_rules('company', 'Name', 'required');`

Do any `one` change will help you.

Comment: I already changed that, but when the form submitted, it gets error cause name can't be null. That means the select option is not inserted any value. That's what I looking for along this day. Why even I already select the select option, the value in the option still null.

Comment: Add this and show what result u r getting? public function masuk(){
        var_dump($_POST);exit;

Comment: the company is not null when I var_dump that

Comment: then $this->form_validation->set_rules('company', 'Name', 'required'); will pass your validation for select field as like i mentioned in answer

Comment: But I still get this error Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Name', table '.dbo.Company'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Comment: Its works now, I changed name="company" to name="name"

Comment: yes ...thats what i mentioned in ans..bcoz u are sending company input and u r validating Name..